# codeigniter force_download() for excel file downloading a corrupt file

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, helper

Following is the code i am using to force download some files on my server in codeigniter. The downloaded file is corrupt and MS Excel is not able to open it. I don't see any problem with this code. I downloaded the files using ftp from server and checked and they just opened fine.I don't know where I did wrong.

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$path = base_url('reference/filename.xlsx');
$data = file_get_contents($path); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'filename.xlsx';
force_download($name, $data);
```

Comment: Open the file with notepad++ or another text editor and check for PHP errors at the top of the xlsx

Comment: There is only encoded data. No PHP errors

Comment: And you are opening the downloaded file with the text editor?

Comment: What is the first character in the file?

Comment: Yes I opened file with text editor

Comment: I don't know how this would help you to debug but the first character is  P.

Comment: it is P, and there is no space before it?  What is the last letter?

Answer (score 2):

Flush the output buffer with the ob_clean() function just before you get your data.

Your code should now look like this.

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$path = base_url('reference/filename.xlsx');

ob_clean();

$data = file_get_contents($path); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'filename.xlsx';
force_download($name, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and CI does not support xlsx by default. You will have to find some lib to do this. Anyway, you can download as csv if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out downloading Excel xlsx-files works just fine if you use force_download() inside a model before any html content is loaded. I am using force_download inside my navigation model before any views are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. but path is incorrect.but not display error message. comment following and run. then you can see error message of path

```
//force_download($name, $data);
```

and fix path to correct and again remove comment and run,then can open downloaded file.